# Button click in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, events

I am trying to understand how this ASP.NET MVC thing works compared to webforms, so I tried to simply call any method that will do the most basic thing, print some text into console, or change the text of a label.

Turns out it's nearly damn impossible to do, so I tried to look it up, everything I could find requires to first make the method in the controller which can be fine, but then it requires to add the corresponding cshtml file, put some tags over there and when you click that thing you will get the page from the new cshtml, but that's not what I want, an example how it's done from what I was able to find.

In `HomeController`:

```
namespace WebApplication9.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult ClickTest()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "ClickTest.";
            Debug.WriteLine("Damn...");
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

In Views -> Shared -> _Layout.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" title="more options">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("Application name", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div id="test-nav" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Click", "ClickTest", "Home")</li>
                </ul>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

The last step is to add `ClickTesty.cshtml` in Views -> Home, but that's not at all what I want to do, and all the examples of a click that I was able to find show this approach, except they do other things, but what if I just want to change a label text or hide something on a current page not a new one? I couldn't find any info how to do it using C#, in webforms there's no problem to change some text or hide something on the current page, even using javascript, but here I can't find a way.

Answer (score 0):

To see a Debug.WriteLine in Visual Studio here's what you can do:

1. Add this code:

> ```
> <input type="button" value="Click here to debug log" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("ClickTest", "Home")'" />
> ```

Inside the "main" tag on your application
[image]

2. HomeController should look something like this:

> ```
> public IActionResult ClickTest()
> {
>     Debug.WriteLine("Damn...");
>     return View("Index");
> }
> ```

3. Run the application in Debug mode (F5 by default)
4. Go to the Home page, click the button 'Click here to debug log'
5. You will see at the Output pane your Debug.WriteLine
   [image]

What you are doing right now on your code is to redirect to a different view that doesn't exists. So, returning the View("Index") is doing the trick to not have an error and see your log.